# JSF textarea and newline, what is stored on server side?

Tags: java, jsf

There is a `<textarea>` element on a JSF page, user inputs several lines and submits the form. What line delimiter do I expect on the server side?

- `\r\n` in case user's OS is Windows, `\n` - when Unix
- line delimiter depends on OS where my JSF servlet is running
- line delimiter is always `\n` (Java
  internal one)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HTML 4.0.1 spec mandates CR LF (`\r\n`) for line breaks in both [application/x-www-form-urlencoded](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1) and [multipart/form-data](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2) requests.

Neither the Servlet spec nor the JSF spec seem to have anything to say about line delimiters.

Comment: is this mean that in *nix OS we'll have \r\n too?

Comment: @smas - a quick test on Linux (Firefox  + Tomcat 7 servlet) shows that it POSTs `\r\n`. However, I haven't tested every browser and servlet implementation in the world, so they may not all comply with the spec - processing lines in a line-delimiter agnostic way relatively easy, so my code tends not to suffer anyway. Either way, you need to either convert or validate your inputs as you would with any other data.

Comment: An implementation is @Osw problem :) HTML spec's surprised me about \r\n, I've been always thinking that \r\n is only under M$, so good to know about it

Answer (score 3):

I think the complete answer is a bit more complicated:

- @McDowell's answer deals with the case where the textarea data is sent as `POST` data.  In that case, the HTML 4 spec says that line breaks are encoded as %-escaped `CR LF` sequences.
- The HTML 4 spec does not deal with the case where the textarea data is sent as URL query parameters; e.g. in a `GET` request.
- The HTML 5 spec says that the "value" of the textarea is converted to `CR LF` sequences, which covers all cases ... including (I presume) the case where the control's value is accessed from a client-size script.  The value will then be %-escaped when encoded for transmission.

In summary, the specs say `CR LF` (i.e. `\r\n`) where they say anything, but it is *possible* that you could see `CR` or `LF` with some HTML 4 or older browsers on some platforms.

Comment: some fair points here; although JSF requires a POST to update the model, that wouldn't stop someone formulating a "malformed" line delimiter param even if every client/server in the world complied with the spec. Inputs need to be converted or validated if they need to be in a specific form.